# Why do Elves, who can see in starlight, have a lifepath called Chandler (candle-maker)?

Tags: lore, elf, designer-reasons, burning-wheel

BWGR p. 131:

> **Chandler**, 50 yrs, 15 rp, +1 M, (Citadel, Protector)
>
> Skills: 5 pts: Chant of Offering‡, Haggling, Conspicuous, Appraisal
>
> Traits: 1 pt: —

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandlery):

> A **chandlery** (/ˈtʃændləri/ or /ˈtʃɑːnd-/) was originally the office in a wealthy medieval household responsible for wax and candles, as well as the room in which the candles were kept. It could be headed by a **chandler**.

Why do Elves make candles at all, much less call what seems to be the generic Merchant lifepath by the name of a candle-maker?

Comment: You mark the question with the "designer reasons" tag, which is probably off-topic. Could you please narrow down it a little? Do you ask exactly about difference between Merchant and Chandler paths? Possible indoor uses for candles? Something else?

Comment: @enkryptor I'm not sure if the answer to this question is going to be a lore answer or a designer-reasons answer, is the thing - there could be an in- or an out-of-universe answer to it (e.g. either elves are candle geniuses, or there was a merchant elf in an early BW campaign that left an impression on BWHQ, or a secret third thing)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is more an English-language question, I think. I wasn't actually aware that there was an association of the word with candles; it more commonly comes up (at least in my experience) when you talk about a supplier of goods for ships. Checking [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chandler), I find that a chandler can be a dealer in a specific kind of good (definition 3).

It's also possible that the lifepath isn't for a type of merchant at all; a chandler can be a servant responsible for buying candles, and I could imagine the authors extending that to being a servant responsible for buying supplies for a household (whether on purpose or through misremembering).

Comment: It definitely makes more sense that "chandler" is being used here as an archaic term for merchant or dealer. Elves, being very old, would use the older term.

Comment: Ship Chandler is a term still in modern use

Comment: You do very occasionally still hear other businesses referred to as chandlers or chandleries. I was confused once when I saw a 'chandlery' that wasn't for maritime goods (I can't remember the details, but it was probably in Singapore or Malaysia).

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I've also come across *theatrical chandlers* who supply prop-making and rigging supplies, etc.

Answer (score 15):

#### Starlight doesn't get everywhere.

> In complete darkness, Elves still suffer +4 Ob like Men or Dwarves.
>
> -- *Burning Wheel Gold*, "Elves: Keen Sight", p.140

Upper and lowercase there. Lowercase starlight, well, nights get overcast, and all those underground fantasy locations are well shielded from the stars. Uppercase Starlight is obviously your phials of Galadriel, but it's also obviously 50 Resources which is going to be kind of a reach for most people.

In contrast to more secluded lifepath settings like the Citadel, the wilderland setting where an Elf can be a chandler is a likelier home to interesting undergrounds both natural and unnatural, and also a likelier place for Men and Dwarves to come for trade, who definitely need candles and will be very interested in buying some when a cheaty Elf has sung the Chant of Offering.

#### The larger "chandler"

The etymology is a pretty clear trace to the original French: candles are involved in whatever a chandler is doing. But in much the same way as you can head to a grocery store and come away with flowers, magazines, utensils, napkins, and various other things it would be a bad idea for you to place in your mouth, chew, and swallow, chandelries often sold other consumable home or ship goods in addition to candles, becoming a common point of supply.

#### "Chandler" as "outside-trader"

There's a case to be made that "chandler" is an Elven euphemism for "outside-trader", referring to merchants who deal largely or notably with foreign clientele. It goes about like so:

- Regardless of whether or not Elves need candles, Men and Dwarves definitely need candles in places and times where Elves do not.
- Haggling is an important skill to both Men and Dwarves where it isn't to Elves - the head of a Mannish or Dwarven household can pick up Haggling, as can a Mannish or Dwarven journeyman crafter, but an Elven spouse/*atriarch or shaper trainee hasn't got it.
- A trader who regularly does business with Men and Dwarves will therefore need to learn how to haggle. ...and also stock candles.

Comment: This makes sense, but it doesn't sufficiently explain to me why the name for *any* elf merchant is "Chandler" - there's *not* another merchant lifepath AFAICT; Chandler is the only elf LP where you get Haggling.

Comment: @order Sorry to say this but I think the short answer is that the BW lifepaths don't really represent a complete and holistic view of fantasy/medieval society. They're more like "here's the stuff we thought of at the time, including some fun tropes and one or two goofy jokes." That is, of course, a very frustrating conclusion.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning other more general roles that are named after singular tasks. A butler is in theory someone who only manages bottles and serves drinks, a very narrowly-defined service within a lord's manor or castle. But the role was expanded and understood to cover many more things in later society.